# Espresso: pullToRefresh is causing Espresso to time out

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso

Developers have implemented pullToRefresh in our app to load information faster. This however is making our tests fail when this screen is loaded. We have set up idling resources for the view as well and it still times out. When we debug everything works accordingly. So it seems like the refresh function is not letting go of the thread.

The error will state that the previous action didn't happen and will also show that there is an idle timeout but leave the type of idle blank.

Error Message:

```
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'performing ViewAction: single click on item matching: view holder with store front category: CATEGORY' on view 'with id: com.COMPANY.espresso:id/category_list'.
at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:83)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:80)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:115)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:87)
at com.COMPANY.espresso.pages.StorePage.chooseStoreFrontCategory(StorePage.java:59)
at com.COMPANY.espresso.tests.SanityTest.testUserCanAddSflyImageToProductandCart(SanityTest.java:112)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1992)
Caused by: android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click - At Coordinates: 359, 933 and precision: 16, 16' on view 'CardView{id=2131886422, res-name=card_store_front_item, visibility=VISIBLE, width=660, height=440, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=30.0, y=552.0, child-count=1}'.
at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:83)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:100)
at android.support.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions$ActionOnItemAtPositionViewAction.perform(RecyclerViewActions.java:303)
at android.support.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions$ActionOnItemViewAction.perform(RecyclerViewActions.java:232)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.run(ViewInteraction.java:144)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5725)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1030)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:825)
Caused by: android.support.test.espresso.AppNotIdleException: Looped for 3215 iterations over 60000 MILLISECONDS. The following Idle Conditions failed .
at android.support.test.espresso.IdlingPolicy.handleTimeout(IdlingPolicy.java:61)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:480)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:411)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.injectMotionEvent(UiControllerImpl.java:229)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp(MotionEvents.java:138)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp(MotionEvents.java:118)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap.sendSingleTap(Tap.java:135)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap.access$100(Tap.java:35)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.sendTap(Tap.java:40)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:98)
... 13 more
```

TL/DR - Tests worked - then Pull to Refresh was added - tests don't work.

Comment: Can you post your idlingresource?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a bug in the Pull To Refresh framework. Updating the build SDK fixed this.